# JTemplate template missed elements

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, jtemplate

I have this template:

```
<ul id="warningMessages" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 4px;">
    {#foreach $T as msg}
        <li>{$T.msg.Value}</li>
    {#/for}
</ul>
```

When applied look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Value 1</li>
    <li>Value 2</li>
</ul>
```

The style and id information (`"id="warningMessages" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 4px;"`) disappears and I don't know why.

Comment: There's a button on the form that allows you to mark something as code (It's got '101010' written on it). Try putting those around your HTML, as-is we can't see any cause it's been filtered out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't reproduce your problem. Check this sample page. Works as expected

http://jsbin.com/icuce

Comment: Now it works, i delete Firefox cache and problem solved. I thougth that F5 was enough byt seems not. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ctrl+R should most often do the trick in such circumstances. But if your javascript was in an external file you must make sure that FF doesn't cache it